# Require password for reboot/shutdown

Tags: permissions, shutdown, reboot, restart

I realise that this question might be forwarded to a pedagogical forum, but I try to ask :-)

I have installed Ububtu Mate 20.04 on iMac (late 2012). I have two users, myself and my son (6 y.o.). When I leave iMac unattended (by with locked screen) he may try to enter. Firstly, he gets to the unlock screen and may press 'Swicth user'. 
1 st question: is it possible to require the password of the current user to switch user (for which you would also need their password)?
If the answer is positive, that's it, if not, then he appears on the screen with the choice of users and in the rigth upper corner there is reboot/shutdown button. Is it possible to require the root permissions to reboot/shut down?
(I realise that it is always possible to switch off by pressing the button behing the monitor, but this is another story.)

Best wishes,

Dmitri

Answer (score 0):

I don't think what you are asking is possible on the system options level.
What is possible though is to replace /usr/sbin/shutdown and /usr/sbin/reboot with two root privileged scripts or small C programs.

These are easy to make. I can help, if you want.

Hope I've helped.